# pass lambda to constructor of member variable

Tags: c++, templates, constructor

Consider the following  classes,

```
template <class L>
class A {
public:
  A(L l) : _l(l) {}
private:
  L _l;
};

class B {
public:
  B(int x) : _x(x), _a([this]() { return _x; }) {}
private:
  int _x;
  A<???> _a;
};
```

I am not sure how to specify the type at `???`. `std:: function<int()>` works, but to my knowledge, this implies virtual function calls (of course, this does not have to be bad, but it would be interesting how to do this properly).

Comment: I think the best approach here is to change your design. I can't tell you how because what you have is a toy example (appropriate for your question indeed)

Comment: Instead of a lambda, you can use a function object with a named type.

Comment: @eeroika so some struct with `operator()`, which takes an instance of `B` in its constructor?

Comment: This looks like an XY problem to me. What is the end goal here?

Comment: @vullumee yes, although to match the lambda, you would take a pointer in the contructor.

Comment: The goal is specifying some custom functionality in `A` via  `_l` (it is some callback used in `A`). `B` uses an `A` internally and has to pass a custom `_l` to the `A` instance, which accesses other members of `B`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than a lambda, you can use a function object that's roughly equivalent.

```
template <class L>
class A {
public:
  A(L l) : _l(l) {}
private:
  L _l;
};

class B {
  struct GetX
  {
    int operator()() const { return _b->_x; }
    B * _b;
  };
public:
  B(int x) : _x(x), _a(GetX{ this }) {}
private:
  int _x;
  A<GetX> _a;
};
```

Comment: @vullumee yes, i think so. Either way you have to be careful with copying and moving `B`s